# Convert only the year part of the datetime in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Any other easier way to bring the year part of a datetime to current year? If not, which one is better performance wise?

Attempt #1:

```
CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, mydate) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + 
CAST(DATEPART(DAY, mydate) AS VARCHAR) + '/' +
CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) AS DATETIME
```

Attempt #2:

```
DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR,  mydate, GETDATE()), mydate)
```

Comment: if this is the source of your performance problems, your database is finished :P

Comment: this is to calculate birthday or anniversaries for some users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance differences are negligible, whichever one is faster.  The differences will be in the microsecond range.

I normally use DATEADD + DATEDIFF as a matter of preference.  The correct format of the VARCHAR version is to use the ISO-8601 format YYYYMMDD, e.g.

```
CAST(STUFF(CONVERT(char(8),mydate,112),1,4,YEAR(GETDATE())) as DATETIME)
```

`CONVERT(,,112)` => **YYYYMMDD**.  STUFF replaces the first 4 characters with current year. YEAR() returns a number but in the context of STUFF is automatically cast as a varchar.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use your first method. It can create unreliable results.

1/2/2012 can be interpreted as February 1st or January 2nd, depending on [settings](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173907?wa=wsignin1.0).

Avoid strings, especially for dates.

Your second method is  much more reliable

Comment: And if you **must** use a string-based date format - use one that works regardless of date/language settings - something like `YYYYMMDD` or such!